# pl sql developer freezes after certain rows

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

***EDIT:***
Interestingly when I do query with DESC it works properly:

```
select text from sys.all_source
             where owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
             and name = 'PCK_REPORT'
             and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
             and origin_con_id in (1, sys_context('userenv', 'con_id'))
             order by line DESC -- with desc it works
```

the issue starts to happen with 19c client installation

---

I can not edit spec&body a package that includes report more than 6000 rows.

After some search, I found I can do:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer 13\plsqldev.exe" DebugSQL

then retry editing package, I have debut.txt in path given below:

> C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\PLSQL Developer 13

finally I found in that file

```
select text from sys.all_source
             where owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
             and name = 'PCK_REPORT'
             and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
             and origin_con_id in (1, sys_context('userenv', 'con_id'))
             order by line
```

when I run this query in sql window after I click "fetch last page", it freezes after 6000 rows.

**Question is how can I set this limit, where is it in preferences?**

---

Edit I use: allround automations [plsql developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/), not the oracle's one

---

Edit II: Origin question title was "pl sql developer freezes after 6000 rows" but I determined that the issue occurs for another package at 700th rows happend.

I can select all rows (more than 6000 rows) with the query below.

```
select text from sys.all_source
             where owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
             and name = 'PCK_REPORT'
             --and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'  --without this line
             and origin_con_id in (1, sys_context('userenv', 'con_id'))
             order by line
```

So the issue happens for some reports including `type = 'PACKAGE BODY'`.

On the other hand,
I can reproduce same issue with command window, it prints results until 6000 th row (700 th row for second package).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842577/how-to-increase-buffer-size-in-oracle-sql-developer-to-view-all-records . "If you are running a script, instead of a statement, you can increase this by selecting Tools/Preferences/Worksheet and increasing "Max Rows to print in a script". The default is 5000, you can change it to any size.". ANy good?

Comment: @TenG close but I don't use oracle pl sql developer but the all round automations one, edited in question

Comment: If its just a one off task for getting the code out, a hacky poor mans workaround add `AND line BETWEEN 1 AND 6000`, run, save output then `AND line BETWEEN 6001 ANd 12000`, etc. Or, Download `sqlci` comand line tool or `sqlplus` in Instant Client and extract the data using them.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak *"I don't use oracle pl sql developer but the all round automations one"* - The two products are called **SQL Developer** and **PL/SQL Developer** respectively. Notice the different names.

Comment: The only preference setting for limiting the number of rows in SQL result grids is the one in casenonsensitive's reply, and that is just for the initial set to be displayed, not a hard limit on what can be queried. And in any case, your initial problem was not in a SQL window but a Program window which has no such limit. Probably this is a question for AllroundAutomations support. Are you able to edit using a source file, out of interest, rather than editing the database source directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here under preferences, window types, sql window:
[image]

If you just have a problem retrieving the metadata, you could do it like this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type => 'PACKAGE_BODY', name => 'PCK_REPORT', schema => 'MY_SCHEMA') from dual;
```

Comment: already tried with "maximum result set size" to zero no luck.More if records per page is set to fixed with value 1000, it may break you ide. I needed to restart pc

Comment: Sometimes the plsql developer has such problems :(. You most likely can only work around with a cursor and looping through the rows. But there's good news if you only want the metadata of your package. Use the dbms_metadata functionality.